# How to add Custom Buttons to Navigation Bar in _MacOS_ App

Tags: swift, macos, navigation

If you look at the Xcode navigation bar:
[image]
The buttons are customized and the bar is taller. 
I have looked at `NSWindow` and the related content but could not find any way to do so.

Comment: Look at `NSToolbar`